# Session variable is null after postback

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, postback, session-variables

I have an ASP.NET v4.0 web application running on IIS 7 on an x64 machine. 
This app works without problems on local developing machine and there was no problem on previous server which was x86.

Problem now is that after a postback all session variables are null. eg. I have a dropdownList that autopostbacks. I've been trying to solve this for hours without any luck. anyone got any Ideas?

SessionState is inProc an I don't have a webGarden enabled on the application pool.

I made a test with the code below. After click the output shows null if i run the program on the new server. But if I run it locally it shows -4 as expected

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="xyz.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsFunctions.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css1.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="css1_print.css" />
</head>
<body class="daBody" onload="HideCalendar('divCalendar')">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="output" runat="server" CssClass="output1"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" OnClick="b1Click" BorderWidth="50px" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
             Session["test"] = -5;
             output.Text = ""+(int)Session["test"];
            }
        }
        protected void b1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if(Session["test"] == null)
            output.Text = "null";
        else
            Session["test"] = ""+((int)Session["test"]+1);
        }
    }
}
```

So it feels like theres a configuration step I've missed.

Comment: Session[test]  or Session["test"] ?

Comment: Session["test"]. made an edit

Comment: There are still `Session[test]`s. The code you showed will throw conversion exception on the second button click.

Comment: actually it won't throw it since Session["test"] is null

Comment: I would start by looking at the cookies.  Cookies are used to track the session.  Is there some configuration in the server and/or browser that is preventing cookies from being used?

Comment: Ive tried with allowing all cookies in browser, made no difference. Kinda new to IIS so I've only been checking the session state where inProcess is selected. And under cookiesettings Use coockies is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that on the new server the URL to the page had an underscore in it.
Made a workaround and it worked like a charm.